# Inheritance Ruby Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord, controller

I have a problem in a project where I have a model called Domain and two more models called Knowledge and Exercise.
Domain keep common attributes and associations of Knowledge and Exercise, beyond that, Knowledge and Exercise keep his owns attributes and associations.
A Domain can be a Knowledge or an Exercise.

I'd create the follow relationship between then models and migrations:

```
class Domain < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :knowledge
  has_one :exercise
end

class Knowledge < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :domain
end

class Exercise < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :domain
end
```

It's working for now, but I don't know if this is the correct approach, and I don't know what steps follow to create controllers methods for Knowledge and Exercises, because I have to create a there respective domains before.

Can you show me the correct approach or tell what can I search for to find this?

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You could also consider using STI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `has_one` relationship for `Knowledge` and `Exercise` at the same time in `Domain` doesn't comply to the statement *A Domain can be a Knowledge or an Exercise*.

I would suggest to create a polymorphic relationship to handle this situation better.

```
class Domain < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :implementation, polymorphic: true
end

class Knowledge < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :domain, as: 'implementation'
end

class Exercise < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :domain, as: 'implementation'
end
```

This way, a `domain` can have only one implementation (either `knowledge`, or `exercise`, and will cater to your needs better. Of course, you can rename `implementation` to whatever you like.

Hope this answers your question.